# UIViewController popped -> CAAnimation.delegate not released?

Tags: objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

I have a UIViewController on a UINavigationController with a special NSObject that performs some animations on it. The method that performs the animation looks like this:

```
- (void) animateView:(UIView*) aView toPosition:(CGPoint) aPositionEnd duration:(CGFloat)duration delegate:(id)delegate {

[self.layer addSublayer:aView.layer];
CGPoint aViewPosition = aView.center;
aView.center = OUT_OF_BOUNDS_POSITION; // Make sure this image position is somewhere out of the view
CGMutablePathRef path = CGPathCreateMutable();
CGPathMoveToPoint(path, NULL, aViewPosition.x, aViewPosition.y);
CGPathAddQuadCurveToPoint(path, NULL, aPositionEnd.x, aViewPosition.y, aPositionEnd.x, aPositionEnd.y);

// Uncomment this to draw the path the thumbnail will fallow
// [_mainView setPath:path];

CAKeyframeAnimation *pathAnimation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
pathAnimation.path = path;
//pathAnimation.duration = duration;
pathAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CABasicAnimation *scaleAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"transform"];
CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeScale(0.1, 0.1, 1.0);
scaleAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCATransform3D:t];
scaleAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

CABasicAnimation *alphaAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"opacity"];
alphaAnimation.toValue = [NSNumber numberWithFloat:0.0f];   
alphaAnimation.removedOnCompletion = NO;

//CABasicAnimation *rotationAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@""];
//CATransform3D t = CATransform3DMakeRotation(degreesToRadian(60.0f) , 1, 0, 0);

CAAnimationGroup *animationGroup = [CAAnimationGroup animation];
animationGroup.animations = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:pathAnimation, scaleAnimation, alphaAnimation, nil];
animationGroup.timingFunction = [CAMediaTimingFunction functionWithName:kCAMediaTimingFunctionEaseInEaseOut];
animationGroup.duration = duration;
animationGroup.delegate = delegate;
animationGroup.removedOnCompletion = YES;
[aView.layer addAnimation:animationGroup forKey:nil];

CFRelease(path);

}
```

'aView' is a UIImageView, 'self' is the UIViewController, and 'delegate' is the NSObject. If the animation completes and I pop the UIViewController, everything is fine: animationDidStop:finished: is called in the NSObject and the UIViewController releases the NSObject in its dealloc. If, however, I pop the UIViewController while the animation is happening, animationDidStop:finished: is called as before, but the NSObject isn't deallocated afterwards, even though animationGroup.removedOnCompletion is set to YES! This definitely happens because CAAnimationGroup isn't releasing the delegate, as it should be. (CAAnimation delegates are retained.) I have no idea why this would be. Any ideas/suggestions?

Perhaps this is in some way related to the behavior I asked about [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6114667/touches-not-cancelled-when-pushing-a-new-controller-in-uinavigationcontroller). Are UINavigationControllers just buggy?

Comment: Why not set the delegate to nil in animationDidStop:?

Comment: If only! I get an exception complaining about CAAnimationGroup being read-only or the like.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I switched over to addSubview: instead of addSublayer: and everything worked okay.

Answer (score 0):

I've a feeling it's more likely to be what you're expectations of the following two methods are

```
animationDidStop:finished:
```

and

```
removedOnCompletion:
```

For instance, when you pop the view controller and the animation is still running, is the bool value passed to the delegate method NO? In which case you couldn't expect it to be removed on completion because you never gave it a chance to complete.

In this case you'll need to manually remove your animations using

```
removeAllAnimations
```

when popping the view controller whilst the animation is still running.

Comment: Hmm, that's a good idea. I'll definitely try that. Seems like an odd design decision if true, though...

Comment: Sadly, this did not work. The animation has no animationKeys by the time it gets to the callback. I discovered that the delegate NEVER gets released when finished: is NO. This may be a bug with CAAnimationGroup. In the meantime, I might just have to call [self release] manually in the callback.